# How can I add absolute positioned DIV sections in a Page Body with PATCH command?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

Let's say I want to add following 2 `DIVs` to the body.

```html
<body data-absolute-enabled="true">
    <div style="position:absolute;left:48px;top:115px;width:624px">
        DIV 1
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;left:630px;top:108px;width:624px">
        DIV 2
    </div>
</body>
```

I was able to [update an existing Page content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-update-page#supported-elements-and-actions) but I can not add new absolute positioned `DIV` section in the body.

It adds the `DIV` elements to very first `DIV` in the existing page so the potion seems has no meaning.

```cs
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

var strJson = "[{'target':'body','action':'append','content': '<div> ...... </div>'}]";
var streamcontent_html_update = new StringContent(strJson);
streamcontent_html_update.Headers.ContentType =
    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
form.Add(streamcontent_html_update, "Commands");
//...

var requestUrl = graphClient.Users[userPrincipalName]
    .Onenote
    .Pages[strpageid]
    .Content
    .Request()
    .RequestUrl;

HttpRequestMessage hrm =
    new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), requestUrl);
hrm.Content = form;

await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);
HttpResponseMessage response =
    await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Basically I want to replace the whole page content with my own new HTML data. Note that the position data works when I just create a new page.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-abs-pos

Have you tried appending an absolutely positioned div, like outlined in the guide linked above?

```
<body data-absolute-enabled="true">
    <p>This content will appear in the _default div.</p>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:175px;left:100px" data-id="div1">
      <p>This content will appear in an absolute positioned div.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>This content will also appear in the _default div.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sure, this is the excerpt of the html I used, which works when I create one.

`<body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
  <div style="position:absolute;left:48px;top:115px;width:624px">
   <p style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&#39;target&#39;:&#39;body&#39;</p>
   <br />
   <br />
   <img width="480" height="320"  src="name:img0_image_jpeg" data-src-type="image/jpeg" />
   <br />
  </div>...
 </body>`

Comment: I think the point is that when CREATE, the same HTML can position the DIVs at given position as expected. But when UPDATE, those contents are created INSIDE the first DIV already exist in the current page. Mayb the JSON command needs to be changed or maybe this is not supported yet.

Comment: Yes it's not supported in PATCH for now. The docs need to be updated. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: I am happy to let you know that we fixed this issue. You should now be able to PATCH absolute positioned div sections in your page body. We only support target=body and action=replace for absolute positioning in PATCH though.

Comment: Thanks, @Manjusha